# making a class with buttons as members in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have inherited an asp.net web app , that passes information to a gridview.  Each row has different buttons and links on it and they are enabled/disabled based on the information received.   There is a very long chain of logic that each row goes through to set up the buttons, which makes it very difficult to read.  Is there a way to set up a class of buttons to make this easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by a "class of buttons", but you can create a custom server controls as a wrapper to the button control, and provide some extra properties or methods to simplify the GridView logic.

Here's a quick and dirty example of a RadioButton wrapper that we built, which extends the properties of the standard Radio Button so it can hold extra information. You can try doing something similar for your GridView buttons:

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:RadioButton runat=server></{0}:RadioButton>")]
public class RadioButton : System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            string RadioValue = (string)ViewState["Value"];
            return (RadioValue == null) ? String.Empty : RadioValue;
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["Value"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you could do quickly would be to convert the DataSource to a report class. You could then move the logic for enabling/disabling into that class (i.e., individual property per button), and update the grid to simply check the appropriate property per link/button.

This at least moves the logic out of the aspx file to somewhere it can be maintained/perused more easily.

For example:

```
grid.DataSource = MyReportClass.GetReport();
```

Where

```
public MyReportClass
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EnableLink1 { get { //logic here } }
    public string EnableButton3 { get { ///logic here } }

    public static List<MyReportClass> GetReport()
    { 
        // get the data
    }
}
```

then the aspx becomes

```
<gridview id="grid" runat="server" ... >
   ...
   <asp:templatefield headertext="Link1" ><itemtemplate>
     <asp:linkbutton id="l1" runat="server" ...
       visible='<%# !(bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EnableLink1") %>'                          
      />
    </itemTemplate></asp:templatefield>
    ...
</gridview>
```